# Text disappears after jQuery.animate in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a weird problem, I wrote a slider in `jQuery` and all seems fine. But when I run it in Firefox the text disappears on completion of the animate function.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/49h89wcL/

It seems that the `<h2>` tag gets twice the top margin I gave it. Someone knows what goes wrong here? Or have a small hack for it?

Comment: I have no idea why firefox is doing it, but you could try to set the margin-top back in the animation finished handlers for firefox

Comment: I think the better way to do this is to use the `position:absolute` but not using `float:right` to do the trick.

Comment: @RLam if I going to use `position:absolute` I can use `overflow` on the top image. @Markai I tried that, but there is an delay so looks a bit weird..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `<h2>` and `<p>` tag into a `<div>` with `class` name is whatever you like. And set margin-top for this class instead of both of `<h2>` and `<p>`. Solved the problem!

```
<div class="content">
<h2>Kompetent und engagiert für die Jugend</h2>
<p>Die Jugend ist unsere Zukunft. Wir haben die Verpflichtung, Rahmenbedingungen zu schaffen, die den jungen Menschen in unserer Stadt bestmögliche Entwicklungschancen bieten. Ich wünsche mir allerdings auch, dass sich die Kinder und Jugendlichen in unserer Stadt wohlfühlen und sich mit ihr identifizieren</p>
    <div>
```

javascript:

```
$(".content", this).css("margin-top", "-" + ($(".full-image", this).height()-10) + "px");
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49h89wcL/3/)

Answer (score 3):

Try This
**Solution** - Just don't use Margin to move the image, instead user "Left" with position relative of Image. It always works in all browsers.

Try the fiddle yourself. It doesn't have much changes.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// Campange Slider
 $('.camp-slider').each(function () {
  

  
  $(this).prepend("<img class='full-image' style='width: "+ $(this).width() +"px; height: 300px;' src='" +  $(this).data("image") + "' alt='"+ $(this).data('title') +"' />");

  $(this).append("<div class='alpha' style='background-image: url(\"" + $(this).data("alpha-image") + "\")'></div>");
  $(".alpha", this).width($(".full-image", this).width());
  $(".alpha", this).height($(".full-image", this).height());
  

  $("p", this).css("display", "block");
  $("h2", this).css("display", "block");
  $("h2", this).css("height", "40px");
  $("h2", this).css("float", "right");
  $("p", this).css("float", "right");
  $("h2", this).css("float", "right");
  $("p", this).width(($(".full-image", this).width()/100) * 75);
  $("h2", this).width(($(".full-image", this).width()/100) * 75);
  
  
  
  $("p", this).css("margin-top", "-"+  ($(".full-image", this).height()-$("h2", this).height()-10) +"px");
  $("h2", this).css("margin-top", "-" + ($(".full-image", this).height()-10) + "px");
  $(".alpha", this).css("margin-top", "-" + $(".full-image", this).height() + "px");
  
  $(this).append("<a class='moreBtn' style='clear: both;' href='" + $(this).data("readmore") + "'> Mehr zum Thema <a/>");
  
  
  //$(".full-image", this).css("margin-top", "-300px");
  //$(".full-image", this).css("position", "absolute");

  //$(this).prepend("<h2>" + $(this).data("title") + "</h2>");
 
 });
   
 $('.camp-slider').mouseenter(function(){
  
  $(".full-image", this).animate({
   left: "-75%"
    }, 1000, function() {
     
    });
 });
 
  $('.camp-slider').mouseleave(function(){
  $(".full-image", this).animate({
   left: "0px"
    }, 1000, function() {

    });
 });

});
```

```css
.camp-slider {
 overflow: hidden;
}

.camp-slider p {
 color: #000;
 line-height: 25px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding-top: 20px;
}


.camp-slider .moreBtn {
 display: block;
 width: 155px;
 background-color: #43679a;
 color: #FFF;
 text-align: right;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-top: -40px;
 float: right;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.full-image{
    position:relative;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="camp-slider" data-readmore="http://www.karl-uwe-strothmann.de/kompetent-und-engagiert-fuer-die-jugend/" data-alpha-image="http://www.karl-uwe-strothmann.de/wp-content/themes/politicize/images/camp/a-alpha.png" data-image="http://www.karl-uwe-strothmann.de/wp-content/themes/politicize/images/camp/a-full.png" data-title="">
<h2>Kompetent und engagiert für die Jugend</h2>
<p>Die Jugend ist unsere Zukunft. Wir haben die Verpflichtung, Rahmenbedingungen zu schaffen, die den jungen Menschen in unserer Stadt bestmögliche Entwicklungschancen bieten. Ich wünsche mir allerdings auch, dass sich die Kinder und Jugendlichen in unserer Stadt wohlfühlen und sich mit ihr identifizieren</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is clearer to see what is happening when you don't have a negative `margin-top` on your text elements. Then the text elements are positioned below the image, because the image consumes the space, and the text is `float:right`.

After the image is animated until `margin-left: -70%;` there is suddenly enough space for the text to be displayed beside the image, thus it jumps up.

I think the best way to solve your issue is to use `position:absolute` for both, the image and the text elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the float and the margin: while the image is overlaying, the float will make the text floating under the image, being drawn to top by the negative margin. after you move the image to the left, the text fits next to the image, so the margin should be set to 0 after the move.

A better way to archieve what you want would be using `position:absolute` and top/right values to align the text where you want it to be.